# Permissions on Windows share being accessed from a Mac - Access denied but should not be

Tags: windows, mac-osx, samba, mac

I have a weird problem for some Mac users accessing a Windows (2012) share where the folders are 'locked down' i.e  users can not create folders, only files.  In essence they have all permissions except create and delete folders (and of course full control).

The server has a strict folder structure and we do not want users creating folders but files are fine.

When accessing the share/folder from a windows machine, it works fine.  I can create and delete files as intended.

However, the oddness comes when accessing the folder from a Mac (same user account) where I get an error

> The operation can't be completed because you don't have permission to modify some items

I know it's not an actual permissions issue as I can manually write files to the folder via a terminal session and it works fine.  It's as if the Mac/Finder is trying to change something on the folder (modified date?) and that is denied so it refuses to write the file to the folder.

If I relax the permissions to allow creation of folders, it works fine but I really don't want to do that.

Has anyone seen this before? Is there a workaround/fix?